# Maintaining data locality in a Dictionary<TKey,TValue>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, memory, game-engine

I'm making a game and I decided that for reasons, I'd give each game object an `int` entity ID that I could easily search them by instead of having to linearly search a list or worse, many lists. The idea was inspired by the ECS pattern and I figured if I made sure to re-use ints when they were destroyed, it would help keep all the data close together in memory and reduce cache misses by a bit. (I know that depends more on access order, just thinking in the abstract here). The problem is I'm now doubting myself and I've read so much that I can't keep the ideas straight in my head.

The question is essentially **if I keep endlessly adding higher numbered keys to a `Dictionary<int, SomeClass>`, will the speed/memory usage be worse than if I try to re-use lower numbers?**

Note: I feel like the answer is going to be "write your own class" but I was trying to avoid that and I don't think I'd do a good job if I don't understand this concept.

Comment: The short answer is you will need to try it and see.

Comment: I find it very difficult to write good questions that don't get closed, so I rewrote this one three times to try and make it more concise, and in one of those versions I removed the line explaining that I wasn't sure how to figure out a good test and that's why I was asking for help with the underlying concept of how a dictionary stores data.

Comment: You could check the source code for `Dictionary` to understand how it works. But honestly - profiling will be key here to see whether the benefits actually occur or not...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay here's my best effort at answering this myself, apologies if I get anything wrong.

Short answer: **No**. If you add higher numbers they just get stuck somewhere into the array until it's full. The solution to the example problem is to just replace the dictionary with a `GameObject` array and use the int as an index, and if necessary write a class to handle expanding it.

Longer answer: I think my confusion came from reading somewhere that a dictionary was just a pair of parallel arrays or something like that. I guess that's true but since it's indexed by hash codes, it's not intended for contiguous index values. So it's doing a bunch of redundant work to handle cases that I'm never going to use it for.

Answer (score 3):

No, it makes no difference at all. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2):

> The Dictionary generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash table.

So, the speed will always be O(1) because it internally uses a hash table, the value of the key doesn't affects it at all.

The only problem you can face is if you reach `int.MaxValue`, that's up to your scenerio.